# Registering multiple versions of packages with `ghc-pkg`?

Tags: haskell, version, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to install `GHC` and `Cabal` on FreeBSD 8.1.
I've installed GHC 7.0.1 (because it's current stable release) and now trying to install `Cabal` (to install `cabal-install`), but it fails with this error message.

```
%./Setup configure
Configuring Cabal-1.8.0.4...
Setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
base >=4 && <3 && >=1 && <5, filepath >=1 && <1.2
%
```

Definitely I'm having too higher version of library.

```
%ghc-pkg list
/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.1/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.10.0.0
   array-0.3.0.2
   base-4.3.0.0
   bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
   bytestring-0.9.1.8
   containers-0.4.0.0
   directory-1.1.0.0
   extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.2
   ffi-1.0
   filepath-1.2.0.0
   ghc-7.0.1
   ghc-binary-0.5.0.2
   ghc-prim-0.2.0.0
   haskell2010-1.0.0.0
   haskell98-1.1.0.0
   hpc-0.5.0.6
   integer-gmp-0.2.0.2
   old-locale-1.0.0.2
   old-time-1.0.0.6
   pretty-1.0.1.2
   process-1.0.1.4
   random-1.0.0.3
   rts-1.0
   template-haskell-2.5.0.0
   time-1.2.0.3
   unix-2.4.1.0
/home/eonil/.ghc/x86_64-freebsd-7.0.1/package.conf.d
   network-2.2.1.5
   parsec-2.1.0.1
%
```

Should I downgrade to GHC 6.x? Or can I install lower version of the packages? (or side-by-side install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to downgrade GHC 6.x.
Originally I did this for `Happstack`. However Happstack needs at least 6.12.x of GHC and installing Cabal on FreeBSD 8.1 with GHC 7.x is too hard. (I couldn't succeed)

I just downloaded and installed GHC 6.12.3 from GHC website, and everything worked magically! Cabal, Happstack installed at once. I failed just only once because of insufficient swapping space.

Answer (score 3):

You've hit on what is known as [Haskell's own DLL hell](http://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/haskells-own-dll-hell/).

You can install previous versions of libraries just by appending the version number, e.g. `cabal install base-3.0.3.2`, although I don't know what restrictions there are with GHC 7.0.1.

You can also create little cabal sandboxes with [cabal-dev](http://corp.galois.com/blog/2010/12/20/cabal-dev-sandboxed-development-builds-for-haskell.html) or [capri](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Capri). These would sort of allow you to start from scratch, ignoring packages that would cause conflicts.

If none of this works and you do find you have to reinstall GHC, can I recommend you use [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/). It bundles GHC 6.12.3 with a number of useful libraries.

**Update:** Misread you were trying to actually install cabal install. I'd just use Haskell Platform. It comes with all this stuff already set up.

Comment: It's sad there is no Haskell Platform port for FreeBSD yet.

Comment: Oh shame. And the cabal-install script doesn't work with the Cabal-1.10.0.0 you have installed with GHC 7?

Comment: I downloaded and installed a prebuilt binary from http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_0_1#freebsd_x86_64 . I'm trying ti install lower version of packages side-by-side.

Comment: For Ghc 7 variants you are supposed to patch cabal-install

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to install ghc-6.12, which would provide Cabal-1.8.  You could use that ghc to build cabal-install for the executable, then switch to ghc-7 for everything else once the cabal executable is built.

However I think you should be able to build Cabal-1.8 with ghc-7.  It looks like the installer is getting confused over the base dependencies.  Try doing `./Setup configure -fbase4 -f-base3` and see if that works.

Edit: if you have darcs installed, you can check out the [cabal source tree](http://darcs.haskell.org/cabal-install/).  This is already set up for Cabal-1.10 and ghc-7, so it should build out of the box.  You could wget the source too if you can't install darcs.

Comment: The errors avoided, but there are a lot of dependancies on other lower level packages. (containers, directory, filepath)

Comment: @Eonil, I just edited my answer to include another (likely simpler) option.  If that isn't a possibility, I would try just increasing the upper versions on the dependencies in the "cabal-install.cabal" file, as the API is likely the same for most of these packages.

Comment: Even darcs requires proper haskell installation... But I found better solution. I downgraded GHC to 6.x. Currently all of things are working magically, but once failed with not-enough swapping space. I'm re-trying with newly configured VM. I'll post solution if I succeeds.